# Adding Files Of A Certain Type To My Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Google Apps Script doesn't like this line of code:

```
function addUser(username, firstname, lastname, email, password, birthdate) {
var users = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B7hKHDOEh8CCfmhNZ1g4LTAwTXlINC04dmEtU2tVbzNMUUtLLVRNRzVSMVJDVzVzM084aFE");
var userFolder = users.createFolder(username);
var profileTemp =  DriveApp.getFileById("10bqqJgIwgOBezYiUC4IOhEYwbtUmKDg1UzJ6XIBsx40");
userFolder.createFile("Followers", "", MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
```

It keeps telling me that I can't use MimeTypes and that I have to use the advanced drive service.
**How do I fix this?**

Comment: How are you creating userFolder ?

Comment: @Sergeinsas I don't have problems with that. But if you must know, I have a folder named "Users" and I get it using the id. I am am using the createFolder(_folder_)  method to create the userFolder inside my folder named "Users"

Comment: Hey Nicholas, that's not "the minimal code required to reproduce the problem" - so yes, knowing what method(s) obtained the folder is relevant. How about updating the question with more information / code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is **Cannot use "DriveApp.createFile()" to create Google MIME types. Please use Advanced Drive service.**

The first part is clear enough, but the advice isn't.

If you want to create a new spreadsheet, use this instead of `DriveApp.createFile()`:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("Followers");
```

Then move it into your folder.

```js
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
var parents = file.getParents();
parents.next().removeFile(file);
userFolder.addFile(file);
```

Your function becomes:

```js
function addUser(username, firstname, lastname, email, password, birthdate) {
  var users = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B7hKHDOEh8CCfmhNZ1g4LTAwTXlINC04dmEtU2tVbzNMUUtLLVRNRzVSMVJDVzVzM084aFE");
  var userFolder = users.createFolder(username);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("Followers");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
  var parents = file.getParents();              // Get current parents - will be "root"
  parents.next().removeFile(file);              // Remove file from "root"
  userFolder.addFile(file);                     // Place into userFolder
}
```